# Why making API call to Confluence with bearer token does not work in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, bearer-token, confluence

I have some strange issue with making an API call using Python's requests. I have looked at similar questions but they all point to the solution I have already implemented.

I am trying to access Confluence page using Personal Access Token (PAT) but I get error 401, and when I check the token page it seems that the token has never been used.

It does not seem the issue is with connection or validity of the token because:

- I tried many tokens
- curl call works
- Authenticating with `auth=(user, pass)` instead of token works.
- curl call from subprocess also works.

It looks like requests does not pass the data correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```py
import requests
token = 'abcdefg'
page_id = 12345

url = f'https://my.confluence.instance.com/rest/api/content/{page_id}'
h = {
    'Accept': 'Application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=h)
print(response.status_code)  # Prints 401

import subprocess
response = subprocess.run(
    f'curl -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" {url}',
    shell=True,
    capture_output=True,
    text=True,
)
print(response)  # Correctly prints JSON with page information
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. I had some credentials information for the host in .netrc. By default requests was forcing to authenticate with data from .netrc

I have solved it by ignoring .netrc:

```py
import requests
token = 'abcdefg'
page_id = 12345

url = f'https://my.confluence.instance.com/rest/api/content/{page_id}'
h = {
    'Accept': 'Application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.trust_env = False
    response = session.get(url, headers=h)

print(response.status_code)  # Prints 200!
```